# Cannot send signal to another process in perl

Tags: linux, perl, cgi, kill

I have to send a sigusr2 signal number 12 to a process named xyz in a cgi perl script. I do the following:

```
my $pid = `pidof xyz`;

kill 12, $pid or die "could not kill: $pid";
```

It dies when I press the button on which this command run.

How can I send signal to a process named "xyz" in a cgi perl script.

Comment: Is the other process running with the same userid? Only root can send signals to a different user's process.

Comment: Try including `$!` in the error message, so you see the reason for the error.

Comment: @Barmar How do I check the userid of the cgi perl script. and the other process.

Comment: I assumed you would know if you're running both programs from the same account. But you can use `ps -l` to see the userids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend your error message by $!:

```
my $pid = `pidof xyz`;
kill 12, $pid or die "could not kill $pid: $!";
```

$! contains the last system call error: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ERRNO

You should also check if any PID has been found:

```
my $pid = `pidof xyz`;
die 'No PID found for xyz!' unless $pid;
kill 12, $pid or die "could not kill $pid: $!";
```

A uid mismatch (as mentioned in the comments to your post) might be the reason. You could use *ps* to check:

```
my $pid = `pidof xyz`;
die 'No PID found for xyz!' unless $pid;
system "ps u $$ $pid";
kill 12, $pid or die "could not kill $pid: $!";
```

The output should look like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 185388  5960 ?        Ss   08:31   0:01 /sbin/init splash
some      3159  0.0  0.0  27296  8836 pts/11   Ss   08:33   0:00 bash
```

The value of the *USER* column should be the same for both processes (the Perl process and the process being killed), otherwise you're not allowed to send any signal (except if your script runs as root, which isn't recommended).